# Checking the length of lists within a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to check the length of a list within a tuple, but I am having trouble doing this within a conditional statement.

If I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
ex_tuple = (['Hello', 'To', 'World'], ['Planet', 'Earth'], ['World', 'Of', 'Earth'])
```

I want to check if any of these lists in the tuple have > 2 elements.

Here's what I have (doesn't seem to be working):

```
if [(len(x)) for x in ex_tuple > 2]:
... do rest of program
```

But, I get an error message that '>' is not supported between tuple and ints. I've also tried using '!= 1 or 2', but I get a similar message.

This seems like a simple fix, but I am having trouble figuring out where I am going wrong. Would appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: `if any(len(x) > 2 for x in ex_tuple):` is probably what you want

Comment: Or this: `if [1 for x in ex_tuple if len(x)> 2]:`

Answer (score 3):

The built-in function `any()` takes a list and evaluates True if any elements are True, and False if they're all false. Put your list comprehension in there, and move your conditional `> 2` over next to `len(x)` and drop the parentheses around it

```py
any(len(x)>2 for x in ex_tuple)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this simple loop to check it;

```
for word_list in ex_tuple:
    if len(list) > 2:
        print(f"{list}: has more than 2 items.")
```

Result:

```
['Hello', 'To', 'World']: has more than 2 items.
['World', 'Of', 'Earth']: has more than 2 items.
```

Comment: Do do not use `list` as var name!

Comment: Thanks @WaketZheng made the related edit.